# Prior/posterior predictive distributions for an unconstrained/constrained PPO model

Tags: r, bayesian, stan, ordinal

I was wondering how one can use Stan to generate prior and posterior predictive distributions for partial proportional odds (PPO) models? I've provided code (written by Frank Harrell and Ben Goodrich, https://github.com/harrelfe/rmsb/tree/master/inst/stan) for an unconstrained PPO model below with my attempt of generating a posterior predictive distribution, not sure if it's correct, and where to start to code up a prior predictive distribution. Any help for this and the constrained model would be most helpful!

Unconstrained PPO model Stan code:

```
functions {
  // pointwise log-likelihood contributions
  vector pw_log_lik(vector alpha, vector beta, matrix tau,
                    row_vector[] X, row_vector[] Z, int[] y) {
    int N = size(X);
    vector[N] out;
    int k = max(y); // assumes all possible categories are observed
    int j;
    real cj;
    real cj1;
    for (n in 1:N) {
      real eta = X[n] * beta;
      j = y[n];
      if (j == 1)        cj  = -( alpha[1] + eta );
      else if (j == 2)   cj  = alpha[1] + eta;
      else               cj  = alpha[j - 1] + eta + Z[n] * tau[ , j - 2];
      if(j > 1 && j < k) cj1 = alpha[j] + eta + Z[n] * tau[ , j - 1];
      
      if (j == 1 || j == k) out[n] = log_inv_logit(cj);
      //    else out[n] = log(1./(1. + exp(-cj)) - 1./(1. + exp(-cj1)));
      else out[n] = log_diff_exp(-log1p_exp(- cj),
                                 -log1p_exp(- cj1));
      //            else out[n] = log(-log1p_exp(-cj) + log1p_exp(-cj1));
    }
    return out;
  }
  
  // Pr(y == j)
  matrix Pr(vector alpha, vector beta, matrix tau,
            row_vector[] X, row_vector[] Z, int[] y) {
    int N = size(X);
    int k = max(y); // assumes all possible categories are observed
    matrix[N, k] out;
    
    for(n in 1:N) {
      real eta = X[n] * beta ;
      for(j in 1 : k) {
        real cj;
        real cj1;
        if (j == 1)        cj  = -( alpha[1] + eta );
        else if (j == 2)   cj  = alpha[1] + eta;
        else               cj  = alpha[j - 1] + eta + Z[n] * tau[ , j - 2];
        if(j > 1 && j < k) cj1 = alpha[j] + eta + Z[n] * tau[ , j - 1];
        
        if (j == 1 || j == k) out[n, j] = log_inv_logit(cj);
        //else out[n, j] = log(1./(1. + exp(-cj)) - 1./(1. + exp(-cj1)));
        // else  out[n, j] = log_diff_exp(-log1p_exp(-cj),
                                          //                              -log1p_exp(-cj1));
        else out[n, j] = log(-log1p_exp(-cj) + log1p_exp(-cj1));
      }
    }
    return exp(out);
  }
}
data {
  int<lower = 1> N;   // number of observations
  int<lower = 1> p;   // number of predictors
  int<lower = 1> q;   // number of non-PO predictors in Z
  matrix[N, p] X;     // matrix of CENTERED predictors
  matrix[N, q] Z;     // matrix of CENTERED PPO predictors
  int<lower = 2> k;   // number of outcome categories
  int<lower = 1, upper = k> y[N]; // outcome on 1 ... k
  
  // prior standard deviations
  real<lower = 0> sds;
  real<lower = 0> sdsppo;
  real<lower = 0> conc;
}

transformed data {
  row_vector[p] Xr[N];
  row_vector[q] Zr[N];
  for (n in 1:N) Xr[n] = X[n, ];
  for (n in 1:N) Zr[n] = Z[n, ];
}

parameters {
  vector[p] beta; // coefficients on X
  matrix[q, k - 2] tau;  // coefficients on Z
  simplex[k] pi;  // category probabilities for a person w/ average predictors
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[k - 1] alpha;                               // intercepts
  vector[N] log_lik;                                 // log-likelihood pieces
  for (j in 2:k) alpha[j - 1] = logit(sum(pi[j:k])); // predictors are CENTERED
  log_lik = pw_log_lik(alpha, beta, tau, Xr, Zr, y);
}

model {
  target += log_lik;
  target += dirichlet_lpdf(pi | rep_vector(conc, k));
  target += normal_lpdf(beta | 0, sds);
  for (j in 1:(k - 2)) target += normal_lpdf(tau[ , j] | 0, sdsppo);
}

//generated quantities {
  //  vector[p] OR = -beta - tau[1,1];
  //  vector[N] y_rep;
  //  for (n in 1:N)
    //    y_rep[n] = ordered_logistic_rng(X[n]*beta + Z[n]*tau[,1], -alpha);
    //}
```

Constrained PPO model:

```
functions {
  // pointwise log-likelihood contributions
  vector pw_log_lik(vector alpha, vector beta, vector tau, vector pposcore, 
          row_vector[] X, row_vector[] Z, int[] y) 
                      {
    int N = size(X);
    vector[N] out;
    int k = max(y); // assumes all possible categories are observed
        real zeta = 0.;
        real r = 0.;
        real r2 = 0.;
        real ca;
    real ca1;
        int a;
        int q = size(Z) > 0 ? cols(Z[1]) : 0;
    for (n in 1:N) {
      real eta  = X[n] * beta;
            if(q > 0)  zeta = Z[n] * tau;
      a = y[n];    
              if(q == 0) {  // PO
              if (a == 1)        ca  = -(alpha[1]     + eta);
              else if (a == 2)   ca  =   alpha[1]     + eta;
              else               ca  =   alpha[a - 1] + eta;
                if(a > 1 && a < k) ca1 =   alpha[a]     + eta;
                }
                else {
              if (a == 1)        ca  = -( alpha[1]     + eta + pposcore[2]   * zeta);
              else if (a == 2)   ca  =    alpha[1]     + eta + pposcore[2]   * zeta;
              else               ca  =    alpha[a - 1] + eta + pposcore[a]   * zeta;
                if(a > 1 && a < k) ca1 =    alpha[a]     + eta + pposcore[a+1] * zeta;
                }
      if (a == 1 || a == k) out[n] = log_inv_logit(ca);
            else out[n]  = log(1./(1. + exp(-ca)) - 1./(1. + exp(-ca1)));
             // if(q > 0) r = pposcore[a] * zeta;
            //  out[n] = log_inv_logit(alpha[a-1] + eta + r);
    }
    return out;
  }
}

data {
  int<lower = 1> N;   // number of observations
  int<lower = 1> p;   // number of predictors
    int<lower = 0> q;   // number of non-PO predictors in Z
  int<lower = 2> k;   // number of outcome categories
    int<lower = 0, upper = k> lpposcore;  // extent of pposcore (1=PO)
  matrix[N, p] X;     // matrix of CENTERED predictors
    matrix[N, q] Z;     // matrix of CENTERED PPO predictors
  int<lower = 1, upper = k> y[N]; // outcome on 1 ... k
    vector[lpposcore] pposcore; // scores for constrained partial PO

// prior standard deviations
  real<lower = 0> sds;
  real<lower = 0> sdsppo;
  real<lower = 0> conc;
}

transformed data {
    row_vector[p] Xr[N];
    row_vector[q] Zr[N];
  for (n in 1:N) Xr[n] = X[n, ];
    for (n in 1:N) Zr[n] = Z[n, ];
}

parameters {
  vector[p] beta; // coefficients on X
  vector[q] tau;  // coefficients on Z
  simplex[k] pi;  // category probabilities for a person w/ average predictors
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[k - 1] alpha;                               // intercepts
  vector[N] log_lik;                                 // log-likelihood pieces
  for (j in 2:k) alpha[j - 1] = logit(sum(pi[j:k])); // predictors are CENTERED
  log_lik = pw_log_lik(alpha, beta, tau, pposcore, Xr, Zr, y);
}

model {
  target += log_lik;
  target += dirichlet_lpdf(pi | rep_vector(conc, k));
  target += normal_lpdf(beta | 0, sds);
    if(q > 0) target += normal_lpdf(tau | 0, sdsppo);
}

//generated quantities {
//  vector[p] OR1 = exp(beta + pposcore[2]*tau[1]);
 // vector[p] OR2 = exp(beta + pposcore[3]*tau[1]);
//}
```

As an aside, I am curious what the values pposcore and lpposcore would take when using the constrained PPO model - let's say I specify a linear relationship between the cumulative log-OR and cumulative logits, what would the values of pposcore/lpposcore take in the Stan model? Or if I specify that only the highest cumulative logit diverges from the proportional odds assumption? (these are just random examples but it will help me think about it!)